# Pending Intent FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

Whenever I'm trying to push a notification then getting this issue  Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent. I Tried so many solutions out there but it's not working.

```
await notificationService.showLocalNotification(
              id: 0,
              title: "Drink Water",
              body: "Time to drink some water!",
              payload: "You just took water! Huurray!"
);

Future<void> showLocalNotification({
required int id,
required String title,
required String body,
required String payload,
}) async {
final platformChannelSpecifics = await _notificationDetails();
await _localNotifications.show(
  id,
  title,
  body,
  platformChannelSpecifics,
  payload: payload,
);
```

}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs in `Android 12`. You can try this code.

into app level `build.gradle` file into `defaultConfig`.

```
 defaultConfig {
            configurations.all {
                resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1' }
            } 
            ......
}
```

Run from scratch again.

Comment: `defaultConfig {
        configurations.all {
                resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1' }
            }
        applicationId "com.review.india"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }`  ~Still not working :(